# Call Async Load Module Function from View

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

I'm trying to asynchronously load a JS file on demand (on user input), that contains another mithril module, with the asynchronous module loader technique described at 
http://lhorie.github.io/mithril-blog/integrating-mithril-and-requirejs.html

The only way I could make this work was to call the async load module function and instantiate the new loaded module's constructor from a base module controller that gets called from a view's onlick function.
Since the documentation states that we shouldn't instantiate a new controller from a view (or call a function that does - this is my case), I was wondering if this is considered anti-pattern and if there's a better way of doing this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/0ayiUsGS1zlwY3x4yZtc?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is fine, since the controller instance is attached to the instance of the Example's controller, and this only happens in response to a click event.

What is considered an anti-pattern is to call `new something.controller` inline in the view, because then the controller would be re-initialized any time a redraw happens (which is most likely not what you want)